# ActionCable channel not accessible outside rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm trying to create a gem which exposes an ActionCable channel, but I can't get it to work.

This is my gem

```
# lib/my_channel.rb
class MyChannel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
  def wait(data)
    # logic ...
  end
end

# lib/engine.rb
module MyApp
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyApp
  end
end
```

I then add the gem to my main applications `Gemfile`, run `bundle install`, start up the console and run `MyChannel`. Which don't yield and error, meaning that the channel as been included properly.

I then add this to my main application

```
// application.js
var socket = "ws://localhost:3000/cable";
var cable = ActionCable.createConsumer(socket);
cable.subscriptions.create({ "channel": "MyChannel" }, {
  received: function(){
    // ...
  }
});
```

But I'm getting this error

```
Subscription class not found ({"command"=>"subscribe", "identifier"=>"{\"channel\":\"MyChannel\"}"})
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Which version of Action Cabel you are on? Rails Beta1?

Comment: @JohnKacz yes, thats right

Comment: It looks like you don't have a subscribed method defined in your MyChannel class. From the docs ([link](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable#channel-example-1-user-appearances)): "Simply calling `App.cable.subscriptions.create` will setup the subscription, which will call `AppearanceChannel#subscribed`"

Comment: @JohnKacz No, that's not necessary

Comment: Ok, sorry. I haven't done much with Action Cable yet (it's on my list), but why is it not necessary? Every example I'm seeing the channel class has a subscribed method.

Comment: Did you release your gem publicly?

Answer (score 3):

**This answer doesn't apply to gems, only making channels within a Rails app.**

Your `my_channel.rb` is located in the wrong place. I'm not sure if behaviour has changed between the betas (I'm using beta3), but it should be located in `app/channels/application_cable/`.

I was experiencing the same issue, and realized my channel file was named inappropriately (`host.rb` instead of `host_channel.rb`). After renaming the file, it started working.

I believe the channel files are only searched for with the specific location and naming scheme (`app/channels/application_cable/*_channel.rb`) by default.

Comment: I think I tried all possible paths at time but I'll try it again to see if it works. Will it be exposed automatically in the gem, or do I've to create a rails engine?

Comment: It is automatically exposed. By the way, I forgot to add the /application_cable part to the path. Remember to add that! I edited the post to add that in.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you were making a gem! You should make Cable aware of your channel somehow. I'm afraid I can't help you with that.

Comment: Okay, I had a look at the source. The classes are searched for in https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb#L29 . So you should somehow get your class onto that list.

Comment: Aand I had another look at the source. The classes are loaded in https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/lib/action_cable/server/base.rb#L61 . The config.channel_paths -list is accessible through ActionCable.server.config in initializers. Hope this helps!